Why does the new windbg clear my breakpoints after .reboot
I noticed that on the new windbg, my breakpoints would get cleared afte I perform .reboot during network debug. This was not the case on the legacy windbg. What can I do to have my breakpoints saved?
I tried saving workspaces, loading the workplace after .reboot but no luck

probably a bug?

It's probably not a bug as I see this across different host machines and target machines. I originally saw this issue almost 2 years ago, which made me stay with the legacy windbg

I don't get it. Why exactly can't that be a bug of new WinDbg?

Check the logs located at %LOCALAPPDATA%\DBG\Logs, searching for instances of 'bu' commands for your saved bps. Cases where breakpoints will fail to restore are
a) Hardware breakpoints (the address will not be the same between sessions)
b) Function/source breakpoints with multiple bindings. Commonly found with templates.
For case b, you can try enabling ambiguous breakpoint resolution (see link below)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ambiguous-breakpoint-resolution
